# leetcode 88 merged sorted array python3 slicing question

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, slice

Here is the leetcode question:

Given two sorted integer arrays nums1 and nums2, merge nums2 into nums1 as one sorted array.

Note:

The number of elements initialized in nums1 and nums2 are m and n respectively.
You may assume that nums1 has enough space (size that is greater or equal to m + n) to hold additional elements from nums2.
Example:

Input:
nums1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0], m = 3
nums2 = [2,5,6],       n = 3

Output: [1,2,2,3,5,6]

https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-sorted-array/

My question is what is the difference between "nums1" and "nums1[:]" in "brutal force 1" & "brutal force 2"?

```
class Solution:
    def merge(self, nums1: List[int], m: int, nums2: List[int], n: int) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.
        """

        nums1=sorted(nums1[0:m]+nums2[0:n])

        return nums1
```

return, which is incorrect.

```
Your input
[1,2,3,0,0,0]
3
[2,5,6]
3
Output
[1,2,3,0,0,0]
Expected
[1,2,2,3,5,6]
```

solution 2, which is correct

```
class Solution:
    def merge(self, nums1: List[int], m: int, nums2: List[int], n: int) -> None:
        """
        Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.
        """

        nums1[:]=sorted(nums1[0:m]+nums2[0:n])

        return nums1[:]


Your input
[1,2,3,0,0,0]
3
[2,5,6]
3
Output
[1,2,2,3,5,6]
Expected
[1,2,2,3,5,6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, including the doc string:

```
    def merge(self, nums1: List[int], m: int, nums2: List[int], n: int) -> None:
       """
       Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.
       """

       nums1=sorted(nums1[0:m]+nums2[0:n])

       return nums1
```

Not sure which part of *"Do not return anything"* inspired you to return something :-)

Apparently the judge is nice enough to not *mind* that you do return something, but it's certainly going to *ignore* whatever you do return. Also, with `nums1 = my_new_list_object` you only reassign your local variable to the newly created list object, you're not modifying the given list object at all. So the judge can't even tell that you did *anything*.

With `nums1[:] = ...` on the other hand, you're not assigning to your local variable, you're assigning to the *content* of the list it references. So that *does* modify the given list object as required.